# How to stop Telegram bot webhook from polling the server?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I set up up a webhook using the official [API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) and everything worked fine, up until this point. I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions as a backend and I got my daily quota exceeded:

> Error: quota exceeded (CPU allocation in function invocations)

However, because this is some sort of status code 500 and no actual response back (I suppose), the bot tries to further call the webhook. Yet, this creates a vicious loop, as the webhook won't stop, causing the daily quota to never become available.

I had to manually deactivate it. Is there another workaround? Some setting?

Comment: Any chance you can add the firebase fn code here

Comment: Sure, it's [open source](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/airdropx).

Comment: I'd like to point out that you should send a 200 response immidiately back to Telegram because you have received the update object. As far as Telegram is concerned their only job is to deliver an object and receive a 200 OK from you.

Comment: So I should just store the object in the webhook, and later process it with another cloud function? I'm not sure that's an improvement, because storing the object also incurs a Promise. Telegram should have a decent timeout.

But anyway, this is not a problem with my code, as explained in the question. Firebase provides an automatic response I don't have any control over!

Answer (score 0):

In my bot, there may have 500 server errors sometime, so I don't let TG know about all errors

Just close HTTP connection before all the other code, for instance, `fastcgi_finish_connection()` for me.

Comment: I don't have any control over how Firebase responds when the daily quota is exceeded. That is the issue.

Comment: Yes, you don't have any control unfortunately on firebase "When a function consumes all of an allocated resource, the resource becomes unavailable until the quota is refreshed or increased. This may mean that your function will not work until then. By default, a function returns an HTTP 500 error code when a required resource is over quota and the function cannot execute." Quoted from Docs.